# Get Posts based on serialized meta value

Tags: wordpress

I have a series of posts and all have a meta_key with the value of "owner" and meta_value with serialized data such as "a:3:{i:0;s:3:"325";i:1;s:2:"41";i:2;s:2:"29";}"

meta_key `owner`

meta_value `a:3:{i:0;s:3:"325";i:1;s:2:"41";i:2;s:2:"29";}`

I am trying to figure out how to properly use `get_posts()` to return all the posts that have a meta_key with the value of `owner` and the meta_value containing a specific value such as `41`

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'rp_applications',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'compare' => '=',
                'key' => 'archived',
                'value' => '0000-00-00'
            ),
            array(
                'compare' => '=',
                'key' => 'owner',
                'value' => ???? WHAT DO I PUT HERE ????
            )
        )
    );

    $applications = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you should be storing the "Owner" as a taxonomy term instead of meta data. It would give you easier and faster querying abilities as well.

That said, it's definitely possible to do what you want. I'd be cautious though, because the `postmeta` table by default is **not indexed**, so a large table with meta queries run against it will slow down your site quite a lot. You may want to consider adding a partial index to the table if it's going to be even remotely large (or again, switch to Taxonomy Terms instead of post meta for this).

If you still care to use a meta query, take a look at the `compare` options available [in the `WP_Meta_Query()` docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters).

One of the available options is `REGEXP`, so you could do something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'rp_applications',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'compare' => 'REGEXP',
            'key'     => 'owner',
            'value'   => sprintf( 'a:\d:{i:0;s:\d:"\d.*?";i:1;s:%d:"%d".*', strlen($owner_id), $owner_id )
        ),
        array(
            'compare' => '=',
            'key'     => 'archived',
            'value'   => '0000-00-00'
        )
    )
);
```

Of course this method only works if the serialized data is in the same format on each one, and you'd need to adjust the regular expression if not - but that should be enough to get you started!

Comment: Since there could be multiple values in the serialized data, I think the REGEX will need to be a little less detailed as it could be anywhere in the value. I am not a REGEX expert but I tried changing your code to `'value'   => sprintf( 's:\d:"\d";', strlen($owner_id), $owner_id )` but that didn't work